# MSSQL - Can select only columns in a row that have different values

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Imagine, I have an audit table that contains the following columns:

```
id   schedule   weekday   weekday_old   weekend   weekend_old
1    week1      m,t,w     th,f          sa,su     sa,su
1    week2      m,t,w     m,t,w         sa,su     sa,su
1    week3      m,t,w     w,th,f        sa,su     sa
1    week4      m,t,w     m,t,w         sa,su     sa,su
1    week5      m,t,w     m,t,w         sa,su     sa,su
1    week6      m,t,w     m,t,w         sa        su    
1    week7      m,t,w     m,t,w         sa        su
```

Is there a sql command(s) that will allow me to select only the rows where data in the weekday/weekday_old is different, or weekend/weekend_old is different, or (when weekday/weekday_old and weekend/weekend_old) is different and replace the values in columns that are same with null?

So, using the above table, I would like the following to be returned

```
week1      m,t,w     th,f          null     null
week3      m,t,w     w,th,f        sa,su    sa
week6      null      null          sa        su    
week7      null      null          sa        su
```

This probably sounds crazy, but we try to do what we're asked with the tools we have.  Looking forward to any help. Thank you.

**I removed week4 from results table. It was typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described doesn't match your sample (why would week4 selected and is not null). Assuming it was a typo:

```
SELECT schedule, 
NULLIF(weekday,weekday_old) AS weekday,
NULLIF(weekday_old,weekday) AS weekday_old,
NULLIF(weekend,weekend_old) AS weekend,
NULLIF(weekend_old,weekend) AS weekend_old
 FROM dbo.mytable 
 WHERE NULLIF(weekday,weekday_old) IS NOT NULL or NULLIF(weekend,weekend_old) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The NULLIF worked perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `CASE` expression like

```
CASE WHEN weekday =  weekday_old THEN NULL ELSE weekday END AS weekday
```

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Rahul, Thank you for suggesting CASE, but went with NULLIF above.